# Vertical align div inside another div without flex

Tags: html, css

How to vertically align div inside another div using property `vertical-align:middle`.

Here is my code.

```css
.hello {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class ="parent ">
  <div class="hello">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

I referred and found giving parent table-cell property and child inline-block works but still not.

**Html**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

### Code Snippet:

```css
.hello {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hello">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

vertical-align works only for display: table-cell, in some browsers you should wrap parent with display: table

```
.hello {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class ="parent ">
  <div class="hello">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: middle` on `.parent` and make `.hello` - `display: block` with `margin: 0 auto`, like:

```
.hello {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.hello{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.parent{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class ="parent ">
  <div class="hello">
  hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!